# PnP Powershell for searching a site in sharepoint for file contains a keyword and to find the access poermissions for those files

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, file-permissions

I search the sharepoint using below code

`

```
$currentTime=$(get-date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
$keyword="Named"
$hashTable=@()
$CSVFile = "C:\Users\Uername\Desktop\SharepointList\mex-DocInventsearchsearchpnp.csv"
$results=Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query $keyword    #-MaxResults 3

foreach($resultRow in $results.ResultRows)
{
$obj=New-Object PSObject
$resultRow.GetEnumerator()| ForEach-Object{ $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty $_.Key $_.Value}

$hashTable+=$obj
$obj=$null
}
$hashtable | export-csv $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Now I have to find the access permissions for each of those files found.

I tried below code for retrieving the access permissions for all files in a list,

```
$Web = Get-PnPWeb
$Lists = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $Web -Property Lists
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Lists[0] -PageSize 2000
$Files = $ListItems | Where { ($_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File") -and ($_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -ne "Forms") -and (-Not($_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef.StartsWith("_")))}
$RolePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $Files -Property RoleAssignments
$HasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $Files -Property RoleAssignments
```

But want to find how I can use in the search result as those are not returned as objects